# Relation between k-th shortest vector of a lattice and (n-k+1)-th shortest of its dual

Tags: lattice-crypto

Let $\Lambda$ be an $n$-dimensional [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) and $\Lambda^*$ be its dual lattice.

For any $k \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, let $\lambda_k(\Lambda)$ be the $k$-th successive minima of $\Lambda$ (analogously for $\lambda_k(\Lambda^*)$).

How can we prove that $\lambda_k(\Lambda) \cdot \lambda_{n-k+1}(\Lambda^*) \ge 1$ ?

---

That comes from the following exercise of a [Micciancio's course from 2014](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp14/cse206A-a/lec3.pdf#page=9):

> Prove that for any $n$-dimensional lattice $\Lambda$, $\lambda_1(\Lambda)\cdot \lambda_{n}(\Lambda^*) \ge 1$. More generally, prove  that  for  any $k$, $\lambda_k(\Lambda) \cdot \lambda_{n-k+1}(\Lambda^*) \ge 1$. [Hint:  For the first part, consider the scalar products between a shortest lattice vector and
>   $n$ short linearly independent vectors from the dual lattice.]

Using the hint, I could solve the first part like this:

Take $v \in \Lambda$ and $x_i \in \Lambda^*$ such that $||v|| = \lambda_1(\Lambda)$ and $||x_i|| = \lambda_i(\Lambda^*)$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Observe that $\langle v, x_i \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}- \{0\}$ for some $i$, because $\langle v, x_i \rangle$ must be different from zero for some $i$ (otherwise, we would have $n+1$ orthogonal vectors in an $n$-dimensional space) and $\langle v, x_i \rangle$ is integer by definition of dual lattice.

So, $1 \le |\langle v, x_i \rangle| \le ||v|| \cdot ||x_i|| \le \lambda_1(\Lambda)\cdot \lambda_i(\Lambda^*) \le \lambda_1(\Lambda)\cdot \lambda_n(\Lambda^*)$.

But how to generalize that argument for any $k$?

Comment: look at this [paper](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~dadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-6.pdf) you'll find the proof of Mr.Ducas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=[v_1,\dots, v_n]$ and $M^* =[v_1^*,\dots, v_n^*]$ be the vectors exhibiting the successive minima of $L$ and $L^*$, i.e.

1. $\lambda_i(L) = \lVert v_i\rVert_2$ and $\lambda_i(L^*) = \lVert v_i^*\rVert_2$, and
2. all $v_i$ are in $L$, and all $v_i^*$ are in $L^*$, and
3. all $v_i$ are independent (similarly for $v_i^*$).

Now, for any $i$, let $M_i = [v_1,\dots, v_i]$, and $M_{n-i+1}^* = [v_1^*,\dots, v_{n-i+1}^*]$.
Let $S_i := \mathsf{span }M_i$ and $S_{n-i+1}^* := \mathsf{span }M_{n-i+1}^*$, and $S_\cap := S_i\cap S_{n-i+1}^*$.
As $\dim S_i \geq i$ and $\dim S_{n-i+1}^*\geq n-i+1$, we have that $S_\cap \neq \{0\}$.
It follows that there must be some $(i,j)$ such that $\langle v_i, v_j^*\rangle\neq 0$.
The rest of the argument then follows the same as before.

For this penultimate step, it suffices to take any $w\in S_\cap\setminus \{0\}$, and write $w = \sum_{j = 1}^i a_jv_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-i+1}a_j^*v_j^*$.
Then
$$0\neq \lVert w\rVert_2^2 = \langle w, w\rangle= \left\langle \sum_{j = 1}^i a_jv_j, \sum_{j = 1}^{n-i+1}a_j^*v_j^*\right\rangle.$$
As this sum is non-zero, it must contain a non-zero term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't understand why the two non-orthogonal vectors must belong to the two sets defined by $M_i$ and $M^*_{n-i+1}$ instead of belonging to only one of them... Couldn't it be the case that we have $v_1 \cdot v_2 \not = 0$, for example?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira oops, fixed.

Comment: Ah, OK, so the non-zero intersection finally gives us one vector from each set such that the inner product is larger than or equal to 1... Thanks!